# The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type , error, how to solve it here

Tags: flutter

Know the problem as the function need to return a Widget but now sure how can I solve this in my code , thanks for the help

```
class PhotoGrid extends StatefulWidget {
  const PhotoGrid({super.key});

  @override
  State<PhotoGrid> createState() => _PhotoGridState();
}

class _PhotoGridState extends State<PhotoGrid> {
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _photoStream =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('photos').snapshots();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: _photoStream,
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return const Text('Something went wrong');
            }

            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const Text("Loading");
            }

            return GridView.builder(
              gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                maxCrossAxisExtent: 120,
                crossAxisSpacing: 20,
                childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
                mainAxisSpacing: 20,
              ),
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                var data = snapshot.data!.docs
                    .map((DocumentSnapshot documents) {
                      var data = documents.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
                      return Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            image: NetworkImage('${data['ImgUrl']}'),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    })
                    .toList()
                    .cast();
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
enter code here
```

Know the problem as the function need to return a Widget but now sure how can I solve this in my code , thanks for the help Know the problem as the function need to return a Widget but now sure how can I solve this in my code , thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  return GridView.builder(
  gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
    maxCrossAxisExtent: 120,
    crossAxisSpacing: 20,
    childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
    mainAxisSpacing: 20,
  ),
  itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    var data = snapshot.data!.docs[index].data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: NetworkImage('${data['ImgUrl']}'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

The error was caused by the fact that the item builder function in the GridView.builder widget was not returning anything and it should return a Widget. To fix it, the function was modified to return a Container widget, containing a DecorationImage showing the image from the ImgUrl key of the data map from the Firebase Query.